# Regarding Tkinter() Based GUI for Arduino

Tags: python, tkinter, arduino

I'm trying to write a python GUI for an arduino, the idea is that a computer will be communicating through serial port with the arduino.

I figured the arduino code itself was too complex to try controlling the thing directly from like matlab, so instead I'd like to control it by sending commands through serial. In addition to that I'm trying to live plot some data.

I'm having a hard time getting the live plot to work without having hard-coded the connection port into the script.

```
def connectArduino():
    global e1
    serial_port = e1.get()
    baud_rate = 9600
    path = "data.txt"
    ser = serial.Serial(serial_port, baud_rate, timeout=0, writeTimeout=0)

def setTunings():
    global entries
    kp = entries[0][1].get()
    ki = entries[1][1].get()
    kd = entries[2][1].get()
    print(kp + ki + kd)

def animate(i):
    ser.reset_input_buffer()
    data = ser.readline()
    data_array = data.split('\t')
    xvalue = float(data_array[0])/1000
    yvalue = float(data_array[1])
    yar.append(yvalue)
    xar.append(xvalue)
    line.set_data(xar, yar)
    ax1.set_xlim(0, i+1)
    print(data_array[0] + '\t' + data_array[1])


import serial
from Tkinter import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

root = Tk()
#root.geometry('1200x700+200+100')
root.title('Temperature Control')
root.config(background='#fafafa')

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack(side=LEFT)

l1 = Label(frame, text = "Connection Port:", anchor ='w')
l1.pack()
e1 = Entry(frame)
e1.pack()
b1 = Button(frame, text = "Connect", command = connectArduino)
b1.pack()

fields = 'Kp', 'Ki', 'Kd'
entries = []
for field in fields:
    row = Frame(frame)
    lab = Label(row, width=15, text=field, anchor='w')
    ent = Entry(row)
    row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
    lab.pack(side=LEFT)
    ent.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES, fill=X)
    entries.append((field, ent))

b2 = Button(frame, text = 'Set Tunings')
b2.pack()

b3 = Button(frame, text = 'Start')
b3.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
#b2.pack(side = LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

b4 = Button(frame, text = 'Stop')
b4.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)
#b3.pack(side = LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)


xar = []
yar = []

style.use('ggplot')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8), dpi=100)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax1.set_ylim(0, 35)
line, = ax1.plot(xar, yar, 'r', marker='o')

plotcanvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, root)
plotcanvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side = RIGHT)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=100, blit=False)

root.mainloop()
```

I must admit I'm a lot more used to C and cpp than I am python so a lot of this I've gui stuff I've been reading about has been going over my head a little bit.

TLDR: Trying to write/read from serial prompt as well as displaying some data in a live plot all with a GUI and button/text entry user input.

Comment: What is the problem with this code? Are you getting an exception from the `Serial` constructor or something? I honestly don't see how this code could do anything useful, because you just create a `Serial` then store it in a local variable that immediately goes away and never even try to read from it, but I don't get how the "without having hard-coded the connection port into the script" could be relevant here—that `e1.get()` should give you exactly the same results as if you'd hardcoded something. If it doesn't, please explain what's different so we can help you debug it.

Comment: So the animate function is meant to read from the serial port and then update the plot. The original application had a line at the very start of the program which established this connection to a software defined port. I'm attempting to allow the user to both select the port from the gui and then give the connect command. The error is that animate is calling the "ser" object without it being defined and I'm curious how I would go about having the animate function intact while simultaneously not defining nor opening the serial connection at startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description in a comment:

> The error is that animate is calling the "ser" object without it being defined…

Right, `ser` doesn't exist as a global variable, because the only place you define it is as a local variable, inside `connectArduino`:

```
def connectArduino():
    global e1
    serial_port = e1.get()
    baud_rate = 9600
    path = "data.txt"
    ser = serial.Serial(serial_port, baud_rate, timeout=0, writeTimeout=0)
```

The solution is simple: just as you added `global e1` to make `e1` a global variable rather than a local one, you need to add `global ser` to make `ser` a global variable rather than a local one.

Then, after you call `connectArduino`, `ser` will be defined, so `animate` will be able to use it.